# JSX and Typescript in the same file with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015:

- I can change a file extension to .jsx and start writing JSX code inside.
- I can change a file extension to .ts and start writing Typescript code inside.

But how can I get JSX and Typescript in Visual Studio 2015 inside one single file?

Something like .jsx.ts? I would like to get intellisense working with both at the same time...

I found this which works with Atom IDE. http://blog.mgechev.com/2015/07/05/using-jsx-react-with-typescript/

As far as I understand I need to have Typescript 1.6 support. If Visual Studio 2015 doesn't come with Typescript 1.6 support, is there any way to use nightly builds which already have this implementation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that TypeScript 1.6 beta is out. Download the tools [as provided in the announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/09/02/announcing-typescript-1-6-beta-react-jsx-better-error-checking-and-more.aspx).

Comment: Beta Typescript Tools for Visual Studio is here now and supports the .tsx extentions wich is Typescript and JSX in the same file [MSDN Announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/09/02/announcing-typescript-1-6-beta-react-jsx-better-error-checking-and-more.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can now create *.tsx files with new TypeScript & Visual Studio